# Simulate a file upload (DropzoneJS) with NightwatchJS

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dropzone.js, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to upload an image with NightwatchJS but setting the value to the input is not working. I'm using DropzoneJS for the upload section.

I already tried the solution from:
[NIghtwatch.js File Upload with Dropzone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715922/nightwatch-js-file-upload-with-dropzone-js)

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" style="visibility: hidden; 
 position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 0px; width: 0px;">
```

**JavaScript**

```
module.exports = { 
  "Upload test": function(browser) {
    browser
      .url('localhost:8080')
      .assert.elementPresent('form > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > input')
      .execute('document.querySelectorAll("input[type=file]")[0].style.display = "block";')          
      .setValue('form > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > input', require('path').resolve(__dirname + '/img.jpg'))
      .assert.valueContains('form > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > input', require('path').resolve(__dirname + '/img.jpg'))
      .end();
    }
}
```

Nightwatch is making a screenshot when a test fails, and the screenshot shows that i didn't upload anything, and thats why the last assert fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploading a file with the Google Chrome driver is working! Just use:

```
 .setValue("input[type=file]",`/path/to/file`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;">
```

The input will be considered visible, but it's actually not visible on the screen.